python packages installation
I received some errors when i wanted to installed packages.
  Obtaining dependency information for cowsay from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/13/63c0a02c44024ee16f664e0b36eefeb22d54e93531630bd99e237986f534/cowsay-6.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/f1/13/63c0a02c44024ee16f664e0b36eefeb22d54e93531630bd99e237986f534/cowsay-6.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/f1/13/63c0a02c44024ee16f664e0b36eefeb22d54e93531630bd99e237986f534/cowsay-6.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/f1/13/63c0a02c44024ee16f664e0b36eefeb22d54e93531630bd99e237986f534/cowsay-6.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/f1/13/63c0a02c44024ee16f664e0b36eefeb22d54e93531630bd99e237986f534/cowsay-6.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/f1/13/63c0a02c44024ee16f664e0b36eefeb22d54e93531630bd99e237986f534/cowsay-6.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/f1/13/63c0a02c44024ee16f664e0b36eefeb22d54e93531630bd99e237986f534/cowsay-6.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))

I expected to  install packages.

The wifi connection is not good. Try re-run the pip command or add -i command,

Regional Limits:
If you are in Iran and trying to install packages, you should know that:
1-If you do this on the remote server, the access of some Iranian servers is -limited and you must use a VPN.
2-If you are trying to install the package on your personal computer, your internet service provider's access is probably limited
3-if you are sure that none of the above is the case, then make sure that a VPN that is limited by the range of IPs is not active on your router or computer.
4-Also, this problem may be due to the DNS setting on your system.
network limit:
1- maybe you can solve this problem with -i option when you running pip install command

-I, --ignore-installed
Ignore the installed packages, overwriting them. This can break your system if the existing package is of a different version or was installed with a different package manager!

(environment variable: PIP_IGNORE_INSTALLED)


2- maybe you have to use a proxy to install you package:
python -m pip install PackageName --proxy="theProxy:thePort"

this is a free proxy website that is accessible for Iranians and maybe you can use it and maybe you want by a premium proxy yourself.
